# how to store the path between two locations?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-layout, android-mapview

i am creating app by using google V2 library and place api. i am able to do eveything perfectly.but my next task is to store the path between source to destination in my database for the purpose if user wants to access the same path again in future then they should not need to search again on map. they can directly access the same path from database. but i have no idea about it ho can i do it. i stuck on it from last 5 days i tried a lot but not getting any solution.please help me guys. thanx in advance :)

Comment: get the lat lang for both positions and store them in database or Shared Preference in form of Double or string and when ever you want to display just get from database and pass it to lat lant like LatLang ltlng = new LatLang(stored lat, stored lang)..thats it

Comment: @MustanserIqbal thax for reply. i tried the same but by this there can be many routes between source and destination. i wants to store the same route means the latlong of the locations which comes between source and destination also stored in database.

Comment: ok let me post answer how you save all routes in db..

Comment: please check my answer

Comment: yeah thanx a lot i tried it.

Comment: if it is working for you then please accept the answer... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to save all location in db use this code hope this will help you

```
public void addLocationToDB(Location location){

  if (mDB == null) {
       mDB = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    }
  mDB.addLocation(location);
}

public void addLocation(Location location) {
        try {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(KEY_LATITUDE, location.getLatitude());
            values.put(KEY_LONGITUDE, location.getLongitude());

            // Inserting Row
            db.insert(TABLE_LOCATION, null, values);
            db.close(); // Closing database connection
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Insert Exception", "Data base insertion exception");
        }
    }
```

and in Order to get Location from DB and o Show on Map use this

```
public List<LatLng> getLatLngList() {
        List<LatLng> latLngList = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOCATION;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(cursor.getDouble(1), cursor.getDouble(2));
                latLngList.add(latLng);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return latLngList;
    }


public void displayRoutesOnMap() {

   List<LatLng> userLocationList = mDB.getLatLngList();
   ListIterator<LatLng> listIterator = userLocationList.listIterator();
   List<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
   PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
   polylineOptions.color(Color.RED);
   polylineOptions.width(3);
   int size = 0;
   while (listIterator.hasNext()) {
        LatLng userLocation = listIterator.next();
            points.add(userLocation);
    }
   mGoogleMap.clear();
   size = userLocationList.size();
//        LatLng latLng = points.get(size - 3);
//        tripLastLocation = latLng;
//        mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 2000));
    polylineOptions.addAll(points);
    mGoogleMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);

}
```